# Per interface DNS vs per domain DNS

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dns, systemd-resolved

I need to switch over to `systemd-resolved` because software (`twingate` client if it matters) that I need to use doesn't work with `openresolv` which I had been using. Reading about it, I've been introduced to concepts such as split-dns, per-interface-dns and so on.

However I couldn't fully grasp the concept behind `Per-Interface DNS`. I can fully appreciate the need to map different (`Routing` or `Search`) `Domains` to different `DNS` servers, but what has it got to do with being *bound* to an interface?

It seems that the desired behaviour is "*given a routing domain ~foo.bar.com, use 30.40.50.60 as the DNS server*". However this has nothing to do with what interface it's configured on. `systemd-resolved` cannot (I believe) magically route the query through the given interface. It can workout the `DNS` server to use for `foo.bar.com` but then needs the help of kernel routing table to reach that `DNS` server of `30.40.50.60`.

For eg. I can have the above mentioned configuration on interface device `eth0` with a completely different associated IP and another interface `eth1` with the associated IP of `30.40.50.60` which is where say a `DNS` server is bound to and listening.

So this is what it would look like roughly:

```
# ip addr for eth0
IP: 13.14.15.16
# resolvectl status for eth0
DNS Servers: 30.40.50.60
DNS Domains: ~foo.bar.com

# ip addr for eth1
IP: 30.40.50.60
# resolvectl status for eth1
DNS Servers: 13.14.15.16
DNS Domains: ~fun.gun.com

# ip route
30.40.50.60 dev eth1 <...>
13.14.15.16 dev eth0 <...>
```

So as you can see, the `DNS` server information bound to eth0 in `resolvectl` actually runs on `eth1` and vice-versa. So now when `resolved` is queried for `foo.bar.com` it finds the `DNS` server to use to be `30.40.50.60` and then routes the query there, and then the kernel routing table dictates that it should be sent on `eth1`, which has nothing to do with `eth0`.

So why is it called `Per-Interface DNS`? It could just as well be a mapping config file (independent of any interface information) that just says:

```
# Domain: DNS-server
~foo.bar.com: 30.40.50.60
~fun.gun.com: 13.14.15.16
# .. and so on
```

This has nothing to do with being associated in anyway with any interface.